# Android Canvas and Listener

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am using a class which extends View for creating canvas. Its name is MyBringBack class. In my MainActivity class, i defined a layout programatically. There is a public static variable in class MyBringBack, and i change its value in some part of the class MyBringBack. 
Is possible to know when this variable changes? I want to change something in my MainActivitiy class by using this changing.

In MainActivity Class

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    li = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasLayout);
    //This is where i have to bring the canvas  

    MyBringBack pcc = new MyBringBack (this);
    li.addView(pcc);
```

In MyBringBack Class

```
public static int score =0 ;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to know when a variable changes, look into listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and actually should) do this using the Observer Pattern.

You don't need your value to be a static one and it is actually breaking the encapsulation principles.

I think some code may lighten you better so I'll provide you with a code example, but first, some explanations:

- A common way to implement the Observer Pattern is to use Interfaces as contractors between an observer and an observable.
- The Observable class will define the interface and create a setter that allows any class that implements this interface to register itself as a listener.
- In the observer side, we implement the observable's Interface and by doing this we will have some methods to implement.
- The observable will simply check if there is a listener and if there is, will notify the information needed through the interface methods.

Here is an example to illustrate how it works :

```
public class MyBringBack extends View {

    // ----------------------------------
    // INTERFACES
    // ----------------------------------

    public interface BringBackListener {
        public abstract void onObservableValueChanged(int value);
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // CONSTANTS
    // ----------------------------------

    private static final int VALUE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT = 1000;

    // ----------------------------------
    // ATTRIBUTES
    // ----------------------------------

    private int mObservableValue = 0;

    private static Handler mHandler;
    private static UpdateObservableValueRunnable mUpdateObservableValueRunnable;

    private BringBackListener mListener;

    // ----------------------------------
    // CONSTRUCTORS
    // ----------------------------------

    public MyBringBack(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView();
    }

    public MyBringBack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeView();
    }

    public MyBringBack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeView();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyBringBack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initializeView();
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    // ----------------------------------

    public void setBringBackListener(BringBackListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    // ----------------------------------

    private void initializeView() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mUpdateObservableValueRunnable = new UpdateObservableValueRunnable();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateObservableValueRunnable, VALUE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // NESTED CLASSES
    // ----------------------------------

    private class UpdateObservableValueRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            mObservableValue++;
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onObservableValueChanged(mObservableValue);
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateObservableValueRunnable, VALUE_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);
        }
    }; // UpdateObservableValue

}
```

In this custom view, I have set a runnable that is run each second. It does 2 things:

- increment an int
- check if a listener is set to notify it with the new value of this int.

Now here is a sample activity that will observe the changes of this view :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BringBackListener {

    // ----------------------------------
    // ATTRIBUTES
    // ----------------------------------

    private TextView mResultTextView;

    // ----------------------------------
    // LYFECYCLE
    // ----------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mResultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasLayout);

        MyBringBack pcc = new MyBringBack(this);
        li.addView(pcc);

        // Do not forget to set the listener (here it is the MainActivity 
        // since it implements BringBackListener)
        pcc.setBringBackListener(this);
    }

    // ----------------------------------
    // IMPLEMENTED METHODS
    // ----------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onObservableValueChanged(int value) {
        mResultTextView.setText(value + "");
    }
}
```

This activity implements the BringBackListener and thus we have to implement onObservableValueChanged(int value). It is through this method that the activity is able to observe changes.

Note that the activity has to register itself through the listener setter defined in MyBringBack : setBringBackListener();

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a method that gets called everytime you make a change to your variable forexample at the points it does so.
You know what pattern lies behind most Listeners? The Observer Pattern. So if you want to amke an own Listener for that implement an Observer Pattern in your Code!